# Kinvey data backup and restore

Tags: mongodb, rest, kinvey

is it possible to backup and restore a data from kinvey using pure rest api?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Meeseeks,

Yes, it is possible to fetch the collections data and then post all of it using REST API. Is there any specific issue that you are facing?

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support